# Connecting eBay API with oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, ebay-api

I waited around 2 months for eBay to enable oAuth 2.0 for my developer account. Now that it is enabled there is a problem.

When the user clicks "I Agree" to complete the oAuth process, they are redirected to the success url specified in my `runame`, but no `code` query parameter is present. In fact, there are no query parameters at all.

Has anyone successfully integrated with oAuth 2? Does it sound like I'm missing something?

Comment: have you complated ebay integration, here i'm trying  for last two weeks

Comment: if you have completed please post some tips on auth

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick I got in touch with eBay directly through their support system. They were not helpful or communicative, but I did get them to finally enable oAuth 2 for our developer account. After many wasted weeks and hours, I realized that eBay's oAuth 2 is completely broken is not a viable option. We did, however, successfully integrate via the original eBay oAuth implementation.

Comment: thank you for sharing valuable information,

Comment: then , i will try with Auth'n'Auth, that is their old authentication method , so it may work correctly

Comment: oauth 2 needs to be enabled ? how we can enable that, because their support is only premium, there is no other way to contact their support team

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick Yes, the premium support costs money. My company paid for the premium support to get oAuth 2 turned on which ended up being completely useless. I know I already said this but save yourself some time and just go with their original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This [guide from ebay](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/merchant-products/merchant-feed/HowTo/oauth.html) might answer your question.

All I get, when I try, is an "Authorisation Cancelled" page:

[image: Ebay Authorisation Cancelled]